# Android Market Upload APK file hangs

Tags: android

I've been trying to upload an APK file to the Android Market for a few days, and the upload process hangs with the spinning icon just rotating.  I've let the upload run overnight and it still hangs.

1)  The APK file is 28 MB

2)  I've uploaded an APK file to the Android market before and it is now for sale.

Is there a way to find out what the error is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Android+Market/thread?tid=43b11f3aa6d2c5bc&hl=en

suggests a 25MB limit. Perhaps temporarily strip some data from the .apk and try again?

Comment: Thanks erique! There is an apparently undocumented limit of 25 MB for apk files.  Once I reduced the size of the APK file below 25 MB I was able to upload the APK file to the market without a problem.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion would be to try a different browser. Sometimes I'll have upload issues (not with the market specifically, I have yet to upload an app) with a browser, and using a different one usually works.

Comment: This is a good suggestion.  I always use Chrome to upload my apps and I've never had an issue.  I'd suggest trying Chrome if you haven't already.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I switched to Chrome, and now on APK upload the wheel stops spinning after ten seconds. But when I try to upload a screenshot, it says "Please upload and .apk first".  I'm guessing there is something wrong with the APK file, but I have verified the APK file is signed.  Is there a way to determine why the upload didn't complete?

Comment: Someone else would have to answer that for you unfortunately. :( I have no experience with that. Good luck!